# Failed to run parity-bridges-common message realy demo

Tags: parity-bridges-common

I an running polkadot bridges from the repository git clone https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common.git
and while running the briges i am getting the following error[image]

Comment: Have you launched Rialto and Millau nodes beforehand? The relayer process must connect to running nodes.

Comment: i have launced both nodes (Rialto and Millau) error is [Rialto_to_Millau_MessageLane_00000000] 2022-11-15 05:30:23 +00 ERROR bridge Error retrieving state from Millau node: BridgePalletIsNotInitialized. Retrying in 0.746009028

Answer (score 2):

as I see, you are trying to run `relay-messages-rialto-to-millau.sh`
but before that you need to run also `relay-rialto-to-millau.sh` and `relay-millau-to-rialto.sh`,

`relay-messages-rialto-to-millau.sh`:

- just relays messages

`relay-rialto-to-millau.sh / relay-millau-to-rialto.sh`:

- initialize bridge pallets (see the error BridgePalletIsNotInitialized)
- relays finality (headers)

Comment: sequence I have executed:1.running both nodes(rialto and millau),   2.running relays.   3.running the relay-messages but still i am getting the same error

Comment: could you, please, add here logs from "2.running relays." ?

Comment: yes, really, there was problem with scripts (wrong account used),
please, update your git branch `origin/master`, there is a fix for that

Comment: ~/parity-bridges-common$ ./scripts/send-message-from-rialto-millau.sh transfer                                  
error: Found argument '--target-signer' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    substrate-relay send-message <bridge> --source-host <source-host> --source-port <source-port>

Comment: sorry for unsatisfactory answer and troubles,
please update repo, right now just this should work `./scripts/send-message-from-rialto-millau.sh remark` (send some Trap message),

inside that script, arguments remark/transfer is wrong, there should be `raw <some-encoded-call>`,
like `raw 020419ac` is `Trap(..)` call,

but honestly, I see `020419ac` in code base, but I dont know how was this generated, trying to find out 

also, we dont really use this script, and they surely needs to be updated:
https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/issues/1406

Comment: @swathi so the `<some-encoded-call>` value is just hex value of encoded VersionedXcm , e.g.: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/blob/master/primitives/test-utils/src/lib.rs#L323

Comment: how to launch millau node in ui

Comment: when i am trying to send messages from rialto-millau i am getting targer-signer error

Comment: Going to retry in 10s
2022-11-29 07:20:24 +00 INFO bridge Connecting to Millau node at ws://millau-node-bob:9944
2022-11-29 07:20:24 +00 ERROR bridge Failed to connect to Millau node: RpcError(Transport(Failed to resolve IP addresses for this hostname: failed to lookup address information: Temporary failure in name resolution)). Going to retry in 10s

Comment: how to launch Millau node in my localhost

Comment: actually, you cannot use polkadot.js.org for Millau node now, there should be needed some hashing algo stuff added to the polkadot.js.org cfg, but we dont have it now, we will work on that "later":
https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/issues/1406
https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/8418

and for the errors related to the `millau-node-bob` (looks like you are trying to run docker version), please open a issue with all commands and environmen directly here: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/issues